# Laravel view not updating after React change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I'm making a basic CRUD in Laravel using React and API Fetch. The Read is working perfectly, but normally without Laravel the content changes using React. In my case while using both frameworks, I have to refresh the page manually in order to see changes.

How to update React component in Laravel without refreshing the page ?

I tried

```
npm run dev
```

I tried

```
npm run watch --watch-poll
```

I tried clearing cache and the incognito mode.

*Edit : I tried BrowserSync dependency and it's updating the content, but with a whole automatic refresh of the page.*

Here is my JS code that I render in the index.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            patients : []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('api/patients')
        .then(response => {this.setState({patients: response.data})})
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
 
 

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">All patients</div>

                            <div className="card-body">

                      <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Nom</th> 
                            <th scope="col">Prénom</th>                            
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                        {
                        this.state.patients !== null
                            ? this.state.patients.map(patient=>(
                                    <tr key={patient.id}>
                                <td>{patient.nom}</td> 
                                <td>{patient.prenom}</td> 
                                    </tr> 
                            ))
                            :
                            null
                        }
 

                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );}
}

export default Home;

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

Comment: Try follow: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#react

Comment: I did. Here is the code I have in my webpack file 

`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .browserSync('localhost:8000');`